# SQL Server Iterating through a table and scrubbing sensitive data

Tags: sql-server, data-scrubbing

I have a table that contains the names of tables and fields that need to be scrubbed.

[image: Sample Table]

I need to loop through this table and scrub the field name in each table.  I would also like any suggestions on a scrubbing algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: what does "scrub the field name" mean?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: create a view on this data and remove the columns you don't want shown... or if sql server 2016 use dynamic data masking.

Comment: be more specific about what you mean by "scrubbing", give an example

Comment: If Customer.LastName is 'Johnson', I'd like that scrubbed to 'J@4krn' or something that is not identifiable.  And similarly, if User.UserId is 'SML23', I'd like it to show 'S4&99'.  Thx.

Comment: By "scrubbing" I assume you mean you want to obfuscate the actual values? In other words you want to take a string, keep the first character and replace the remaining characters with a random character.

Comment: That's correct, Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should really update your request to say data obfuscating.

But that aside this is how you can do it.
First create a function in whatever this database is (Don't alter this part load it in as is):

```
CREATE FUNCTION Character_Mask
(
    @OrigVal varchar(max),
    @InPlain int,
    @MaskChar char(1)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PlainVal varchar(max);
    DECLARE @MaskVal varchar(max);
    DECLARE @MaskLen int;

    SET @PlainVal = RIGHT(@OrigVal,@InPlain);
    SET @MaskLen = (DATALENGTH(@OrigVal) - @InPlain);
    SET @MaskVal = REPLICATE(@MaskChar, @MaskLen);
    Return @MaskVal + @PlainVal; 
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.Character_Mask
    TO Sensitive_high, Sensitive_medium, Sensitive_low;
GO
```

Once you have that in your database, you can start using it in views:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyObbedData
AS
SELECT
    dbo.Character_Scramble(c.FirstName) AS Ob_First_Name,
    dbo.Character_Scramble(c.LastName) AS Ob_LastName,
    dbo.Character_Scramble(c.Email) AS Ob_Email,
    dbo.Character_Scramble(u.UserName) AS Ob_UserName
FROM
    dbo.Customer c
    INNER JOIN dbo.User u
        ON c.UserID = u.UserID
GO

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyObbedData
    TO Sensitive_high, Sensitive_medium;
GO
```

The Character_Mask code was taken from here, it can do heaps more and if you want to read up on it here is the [LINK](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/obfuscating-your-sql-server-data/)

Caz